# ADAL iOS with CocoaPods v0.38 using Swift without Bridging Header

Tags: ios, swift, adal, bridging-header

I am building a Swift App that connects to Office365 using ADAL. A few months back, in the Podfile, I had this single line:

```
pod 'ADALiOS', '~> 1.0.1'
```

and everything worked fine when I defined a Bridging Header that included:

```
#import "ADALiOS/ADAuthenticationContext.h"
```

Finally, in my Swift code, all I need is to add

```
import ADALiOS
```

But I also wanted to start using SwiftyJSON, which is a Swift framework, so I added a couple of lines to my Podfile:

```
pod 'ADALiOS', '~> 1.2.4'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
use_frameworks!
```

Updating to CocoaPods V0.38 allowed to use frameworks with the Objective-C libraries (ADALiOS). According to the documentation, there is no need for a Bridging header anymore, so I removed it.

Now, everything compiles fine, but when I invoke the ADAL code, it fails with the following error:

```
ADALiOS [2015-08-09 13:01:07 - C621BB01-686A-4064-9455-A4B55C11E0E8] 
ERROR: Error raised: 18. Additional Information: 
Domain: ADAuthenticationErrorDomain 
ProtocolCode:(null)
Details:The required resource bundle could not be loaded. Please read the ADALiOS readme on how to build your application with ADAL provided authentication UI resources.. 
ErrorCode: 18.
```

I assume because it compiles/links fine that this is not related to the bridging header but something else.

Any clue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to drag the SwiftyJSON Framework in your project .
Don't Use cocoaPods but download the zip file then unzip and drag the swift files Inside your project .
Like that no need to add use_frameworks in your PodFile and everything should work fine.
(I already done that with another Library and it worked)

Comment: Yes, this could be a workaround, but I was hoping to continue using Cocoapods to manage dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed this issue. In case someone else gets the same "type" of error, this is what I did.

I started a new project from scratch and installed ADALiOS using CocoaPod, without the use_framework! and added manually the library libADALiSO.a to the project, as well as a Bridging Header with the #import "ADAuthenticationContext.h". I even used an older version of ADALiOS (V1.0.2). When trying to run this project (which should have worked), I received strange warnings stating that I had duplicated functions in some hidden folders used by Xcode:

```
~/Library/developer/xcode/DerivedData
~/Library/developer/xcode/CoreSimulator/Device
```

In any case, it worked since it took one of the duplicate to ru the program. Then I just deleted the folders/files with my project name in it and rebuilt the program. The warnings went away and it worked again.

Then, I included in my Podfile the desired PromiseKit and the use_frameworks, rebuilt the app and it worked again. I removed the bridging header which is not required, but only added the following line in my swift code:

```
import ADALiOS
```

and it still worked as it was supposed to in the first place.

Finally, I opened my original project with all my code and it also built and ran without any errors. So I wasted a good 3 hours to retry everything from scratch, thinking that Cocoapods V0.38, or aven ADALiOS were the culprits, to finally find that it probably was just something in Xcode.

So I have no idea why these files caused the issues, and I someone can add an explanation, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

According to the ADAL GitHub repository, this is supposed to be fixed in ADAL 2.1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pods with Objective-C project. Then please use pod version 2.5.1 as this is the latest version available. But unfortunately this version is not mentioned anywhere, the posts and helping blogs still shows 2.2 version which gives compiler error.

But if you have used 2.2 version at initial stage then dont worry, just 'pod update' your project, then reopen the respective workspace. This will make your code compile without any error.